# PHP Calling shell_exec on a bash script running a background process times out

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script with a few lines similar to the following

```
echo "Do something"
/bin/sh -c 'echo $$>pidfile && exec "command"' &
echo "Ran Command">/path/to/outputfile.txt
exit 0
```

Then I call that from a PHP script
`return shell_exec("/path/to/bash/script arguments");`

Now, when I do that, the command is run successfully, and outputfile.txt contains "Ran Command".

However, the PHP script times out after 10ish seconds.  **The bash script takes about 2-3 seconds to run**

If I change the line to
`return shell_exec("/path/to/bash/script arguments >/dev/null 2>&1");`

Then it executes and the PHP script doesn't time out.

I understand why redirecting the output lets PHP continue executing, but I can't figure out why PHP is timing out in the first place requiring me to do that.  Can someone give me some assistance with this?

Comment: The `bin/sh` should use `2>&1 &` instaed of `&` only, because you are moving the script into the background, but the outpu is still piped whitin the bash script. maybe PHP waits vor stdin/stderr to close.

Comment: If that was the case, shouldn't the same timeout (or apparent hang) occur if I manually run `/path/to/bash/script arguments`?  It doesn't.  Only when I run that through php's shell_exec() does the time out happen.

Comment: `>/dev/null 2>&1 &` look here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70963/difference-between-2-2-dev-null-dev-null-and-dev-null-21#70971

Comment: `the same timeout` maybe you will  not see an output, but the /bin/sh can still be running. check this with `htop` or  `ps -Af`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I was using the `>/dev/null` part, I knew you meant that.  Is there any reason to put it in the bash script rather than the PHP script?

Comment: You dont really use it in PHP, u are using it outside the bash/script to pipe that output to dev/null and you dont have return value in PHP then. if you are using it within the bash at one line , every output from that line will be piped into what you have set up.

Comment: And the important part in my comment was, that you are using `&` in the bash and that puts the code in the line into the background and goes straight to the next line, if `&` is not here, the bash script waits until the code in the line is done.

Comment: Try this at command line and see the diffrence: `/bin/sh -c 'sleep 5'` and `/bin/sh -c 'sleep 5' &`

Comment: That's where you losing me.  My bash script DOES have the &.  What is PHP waiting for.  It's executing the bash script (which includes the &).

Comment: `What is PHP waiting for` maybe for the non piped output to close (maybe the are non seeable linebreaks or else ). And that all is just to help out. give hint & directions. No straight answer.  PHP calling BASH is always a little tricky.

Comment: Your tryout with `>/dev/null 2>&1` pipes the output so PHP does not have to wait for anything there. and thats why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this two versions and you get it:

test1.sh
`/bin/sh -c 'sleep 10' >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

test2.sh
`/bin/sh -c 'sleep 10' &`

run both with php on command line like

test1.php
`<?php shell_exec('test1.sh');`

test2.php
`<?php shell_exec('test2.sh');`

and see the difference.

test2.sh is taking 10ish seconds and test1.sh is working like your

`return shell_exec("/path/to/bash/script arguments >/dev/null 2>&1");`

Comment: It does work and I'll mark this as the solution (I'll put the `>/dev/null 2>&1` part in the bash script), but I'm still a bit at a loss.  Running those under PHP they do behave differently.  However, in bash, `./test1.sh` and `./test2.sh` execute exactly the same,